# Cross access between two classes

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, clang

I have two classes that both have to call public methods on each other. The problem is that one of those classes has to be defined first. So when I define the one class it has to call methods from the other class that is not yet defined. The forward declaration of class B also doesn't help. This way the compiler only knows that class B exists but not which members it has. But the compiler needs to know them when changeB() gets defined.

Here a simplified example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A {
    public:
        B* b;
        int data = 0;

        void changeB(){
            b->data = 5;
        }
};

class B {
    public:
        A* a;
        int data = 0;

        void changeA(){
            a->data = 5;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    A a;
    B b;

    a.b = &b;
    b.a = &a;

    a.changeB();
    b.changeA();

    std::cout << "a.data: " << a.data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.data: " << b.data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this (clang++ under Windows 10) I get

```
.\CrossClassAccess.cpp:12:14: error: member access into incomplete type 'B'
            b->data = 5;
             ^
.\CrossClassAccess.cpp:3:7: note: forward declaration of 'B'
class B;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

After I made this simple example I thought perhaps it would help if I first declare both classes and then define the methods. Until a certain point, it helped and showed the expected solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A {
    public:
        B* b;
        int data = 0;

        void changeB();
};

class B {
    public:
        A* a;
        int data = 0;

        void changeA();
};

void A::changeB(){
    b->data = 5;
}

void B::changeA(){
    a->data = 5;
}

// main() is still the same
```

But I wanted to get this closer to reality to understand why this doesn't work in my actual project. so I split up the file into a main file, two cpp files, and two headers. After this, it didn't work anymore.

CrossClassAccessMain.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "CrossClassAccessA.hpp"
#include "CrossClassAccessB.hpp"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    A a;
    B b;

    a.b = &b;
    b.a = &a;

    a.changeB();
    b.changeA();

    std::cout << "a.data: " << a.data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.data: " << b.data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

CrossClassAccessA.hpp

```cpp
class B;

class A {
    public:
        B* b;
        int data = 0;

        void changeB();
};
```

CrossClassAccessB.hpp

```cpp
class A;

class B {
    public:
        A* a;
        int data = 0;

        void changeA();
};
```

CrossClassAccessA.cpp

```cpp
#include "CrossClassAccessA.hpp"

void A::changeB(){
    b->data = 5;
}
```

CrossClassAccessB.cpp

```cpp
#include "CrossClassAccessB.hpp"

void B::changeA(){
    a->data = 5;
}
```

When I compile this I get this error again

```
.\CrossClassAccessA.cpp:4:6: error: member access into incomplete type 'B'
    b->data = 5;
     ^
./CrossClassAccessA.hpp:1:7: note: forward declaration of 'B'
class B;
      ^
1 error generated.
.\CrossClassAccessB.cpp:4:6: error: member access into incomplete type 'A'
    a->data = 5;
     ^
./CrossClassAccessB.hpp:1:7: note: forward declaration of 'A'
class A;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

The command I'm using to compile is

```
clang++ .\CrossClassAccessMain.cpp .\CrossClassAccessA.cpp .\CrossClassAccessB.cpp
```

When I change the order of CrossClassAccessA and CrossClassAccessB I get the same error just with a flipped order.
For me it looks like that one cpp file gets compiled before the other header file was parsed.
**So how can I bring the compilation process in the order of my example that was working, even if I split up my code into different files?**
For this example, I was using clang++. In my main project I'm using Arduino and I'm compiling it over the command line with arduino_debugger.exe. I think in the backend it's using the avr-gcc compiler. I'm not sure if I can pass compiler flags to arduino_debugger.exe. If not (I'm pretty sure that alternatively) I could also compile it directly with avr-gcc (but it would be not as simple as with arduino_debugger.exe).

Comment: Shouldn't you `#include "CrossClassAccessA.hpp"` in `B` and `#include "CrossClassAccessB.hpp"` in `A` too ?

Comment: You have to `#include "CrossClassAccessB.hpp"` in `CrossClassAccessA.cpp` (and similarly for the other source file).

Comment: That helped where it's not important and it didn't where it is.
See my comment under molbdnilo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need the definitions of the classes if you want to use them, so you need to include both headers in both files.
Since the headers don't use the "other" class except by name, this will not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right. When I made this example that slipped through. In my main project, I actually did that but there I still get this error `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Grid'`.
After I corrected the simple example there it worked.